# Add-DistributionGroupMember/Remove-DistributionGroupMember is not recognized from Managed Code Base

Tags: c#, iis, exchange-server-2013, exchange-server-2019

New to Exchange Management.

Our .NET Web App is hosted in IIS. IIS Application Pool Identity is having permissions to establish the connection.

**Before Migration:** Exchange Management Shell 2013 , Windows Server 2012.

**After Migration:** Exchange Management Shell 2019, Windows Server 2022.

We are connecting to the Exchange Server and adding/removing the members from the Distribution List from our code base as below.

***Case 1:***

```
public class ExchangeCmdletHepler 
{
    Runspace m_runspace = null;

    public ExchangeCmdletHepler()
    {
                m_runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                m_runspace.Open();
                
                connectToExchange();
    }

    private void connectToExchange()
    {
                Pipeline pipeline = m_runspace.CreatePipeline();
                
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer <Exchange Server Here> ");            

                pipeline.Invoke();
    }

    public void AddDistributionGroupMember(Object Identity, Object Member, Object DomainController)
    {
        Command cmd = new Command("Add-DistributionGroupMember");           
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Member", Member);
       
        Pipeline pipline = m_runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipline.Commands.Add(cmd);

        Collection<PSObject> resList = pipline.Invoke();
        //process result of resList;
    }
    
    public void RemoveDistributionGroupMember(Object Identity, Object Member, Object DomainController)
    {
        Command cmd = new Command("Remove-DistributionGroupMember");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Member", Member);
        
        Pipeline pipline = m_runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipline.Commands.Add(cmd);
        
        Collection<PSObject> resList = pipline.Invoke();
        //process result of resList;
    }
    
}
```

If I invoke the AddDistributionGroupMember(), then I am getting error as
**The term 'Add-DistributionGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.**

Like wise, If I invoke the RemoveDistributionGroupMember() then I am getting error as, **"The term 'Remove-DistributionGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."**

**Likewise few more commands like New-DistributionGroup,Set-DistributionGroup,Get-PSSession are not working in Case 1.**

***Case 2:***

But if I establis the Exchange Server connection as below, then I got the response without any issue for AddDistributionGroupMember() and RemoveDistributionGroupMember()

```
public class ExchangeCmdletHepler 
{
    Runspace m_runspace = null;

    public ExchangeCmdletHepler()
    {
        //As in Case 1              
    }

    private void connectToExchange()
    {
        var pipleLine = m_runspace.CreatePipeline();

        pipleLine.Commands.AddScript(
          String.Format("$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<ExchangeServerHere>/PowerShell/", exchangeHost)
          );
        pipleLine.Commands.AddScript("Import-PSSession -Session $Session -AllowClobber");

        pipleLine.Invoke();
    }

    public void AddDistributionGroupMember(Object Identity, Object Member, Object DomainController)
    {
        Command cmd = new Command("Add-DistributionGroupMember");           
        //As in Case 1
    }
    
    public void RemoveDistributionGroupMember(Object Identity, Object Member, Object DomainController)
    {
        Command cmd = new Command("Remove-DistributionGroupMember");
        //As in Case 1
    }
}
```

***Case 3:***

But, if I execute any of the above commands (Ex: Add-DistributionGroupMember, Remove-DistributionGroupMember, New-DistributionGroup) in the "**Exchange Management Shell**" then I am getting the response without any issue.

I could see that, **Exchange Management Shell -> Properties -> Target**, it is pointing to

***"
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer {{{ServerHere}}} -ClientApplication:ManagementShell -Prefix Prompt "

"***

1. I am confused because, Case 1 C# Code and Case 3 Exchange Powershell is using same to same command to connect. If the commands are executed in the Exchange Powershell then why it is not executed in my Case 1 C# Scenario?
2. The Case 1 code base working fine before migration (in Exchange Server 2013). But, it is not working after migration (in Exchange Server 2019)

Could some one share some inputs here.

Thanks.